# Google Play Billing backend notifications about purchases

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

Google Play Billing allows get notifications about subscriptions that users make in the app. There is a doc describes how to use this feature https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications

But the doc says only about *subscription* not about *one time purchases* that users make in the app within google play.

I can't find any information related with notifications about single purchases, not subscriptions. **Is anyone know how is it possible to get notifications about purchases?**

Answer (score 1):

They don't offer it. You will get email from Google Play for one-time purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Google documentation was updated. Because in this link that you shared, we can see that the information about one-time purchases (or product purchases) is on the `OneTimePurchasing` tag.
Also, we must pay attention to what the documentation says:

```
If this field is present, then this notification is related to a one-time 
purchase, and this field contains additional information related to the 
purchase. Note that this field is mutually exclusive with testNotification 
and subscriptionProductNotification.
```